# How to update table after inserting values and set value for empty field using WHERE in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have simple function for insert words to database:

```
public function insertNewWords($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($value) {
            DB::table('words')->updateOrInsert(['word' => $value], ['word' => $value]);
        }); 
    }
}
```

And I have simple array with description of words:

```
$array = array('apple' => 'fruit', 'banana' => 'vegetable');
```

How I can add this array to database using `updateOrInsert()` and `where()`.
Now in my table with words have only words and field with description words is empty (default null). I need to simple query: `UPDATE words(description) SET description = $description WHERE word = $word;`

Comment: Values missing in update query .

Comment: What you want to do is not clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Add **description** value.

```
public function insertNewWords($array)
{
    // descriptions array with word as key
    $descriptions = array('apple' => 'fruit', 'banana' => 'vegetable');

    foreach ($array as $key => $word) {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($word) {

            DB::table('words')->updateOrInsert(['word', 'description'], [$word, $descriptions[$word]]); 

        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function insertNewWords($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $word => $description) {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($word, $description) {
            DB::table('words')->updateOrInsert(['word' => $word], ['description' => $description]);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    DB::transaction(function() use ($key, $value) {
        DB::table('words')->where('word', $value)->update(['description' => $key]);
    }); 
}
```